# awk print two variables on the same line

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I need to use awk to print two variables on the same line

```
foo=multiline pattern
bar=multiline pattern

awk -v foo="$foo" -v bar="$bar" 'BEGIN {print foo bar}'
```

This Output:

```
foo1
foo2
foo3
bar1
bar2
bar3
```

I need to get

```
foo1 bar1
foo2 bar2
foo3 bar3
```

Comment: That script can only produce the output you say it does if the variable `foo` contains the string `foo1\nfoo2\nfoo3\n` and the variable `bar` contains `bar1\nbar2\nbar3\n`. If that's what `multiline pattern` means then you are simply getting what you asked for. Edit your question to show the actual settings of your shell variables and clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste` for side-by-side output:

```
paste <(echo "$foo") <(echo "$bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to complicate things. If you want to split the file into two columns with space delimiter in between do this.

```
$ pr -2ts' ' <foobar
```